# Android app with libgdx crashes after 64 bit upgrade

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have an old android game with libgdx 1.6 32 bit, I added the 64 bit *.so files to support 64 bit architecture:

```
"/lib/x86_64/"
"/lib/armeabi-v8a/"
```

but it craches on startup

Comment: You would need to add the .so files from the exact same version of libGDX that you're using. Are you sure that you did? It would also help to see what the crash message says.

Comment: is there any so files (64bit) for libgdx 1.6 ?

Comment: I don't know. That version is super old. I'm not sure how you would even find them if they did exist.